# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.1.0) - How to make the carbon console show application names?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2am-4.1.0 and in the carbon console under the service providers, it shows the service providers' id instead of the corresponding application name created in the devportal.

Is it possible to make the carbon console show the corresponding application name instead of the service provider ID?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do that. In the latest versions, that name was removed to a uuid intentionally. If you need to find the name related to that SP, one option is to get the client id of related to that OAuth application and query Apim database. Application name to consumer key is stored in apim database.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour in APIM 4.x.x versions is to generate the SP name with the UUID.

One workaround would be to use the system property `-Doverride.sp.name=false`.  You will have to modify the SP name manually in the management console. But when this property is there, it will prevent the name being overridden in consequent application updates from the devportal.